# MYSQL: Group several rows under one ID, don't combine

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have a table that looks like this

```
ID          user_input    response        timestamp
-------     --------      -----------     -----------     
123         input          string         1111111111
123         input1         string1        1111111111
123         input2         string2        1111111111

456         input          string         1111111112
456         input1         string1        1111111112
456         input2         string2        1111111112
```

How do I format my query so I get a result set like this?

```
ID  123        
user_input    response        timestamp
--------      -----------     -----------     
input          string         1111111111
input1         string1        1111111111
input2         string2        1111111111

ID  456
user_input    response        timestamp
--------      -----------     ----------- 
input          string         1111111112
input1         string1        1111111112
input2         string2        1111111112
```

If I use group by, the rows get comined into one, and I only get the values of the last rows

Comment: `ORDER BY ID, user_input, response`. You don’t need to use multiple resultsets because the output data has the same schema and the same source table. You also don’t need to use query windowing/portioning as that’s for window-functions.

Comment: SQL is about managing *tables*. You seem to be asking more of a data display question. Such concern should be taken care of in your application itself, not in the database.